# How to add padding to BottomNavigationBarItem.label

Tags: flutter

Before in BottomNavigationBar.title we can add style and padding.

But title is already deprecated and now we need to use `selectedLabelStyle` to style the label. But what if i need to add padding to the label? what should we use?

Before we can do this:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  title: Padding(....child: Text(...))
)
```

But i'm not sure how to do it now in label?

Comment: Instead of adding padding, did you tried to add spaces in your string? Maybe not a good solution but you can write your label "label" like "          label". This may give it a look as you wanted. And I assume you are talking about BottomNavigationBarItem?

Comment: @aoiTenshi yes, i am talking about the BottomNavigationBarItem. i want to add padding below the text. e.g. EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. title is **Deprecated** by flutter refer documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/bottom-navigation-title-to-label)

Refer [**`BottomNavigationBar`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

```
 BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.business),
        ),
        label: 'Business',
      ),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: thanks, but i want to put padding on the bottom of label.